# Location of java.security and deployment.properties files

Tags: macos, java

Where are java.security and deployment.properties files located on Mac OS Yosemite??

Comment: If you know the filename, you could try something like `find / -name 'java.security*' -print` from a command line.

Comment: I did this and found it, however, Terminal doesn't like spaces (e.g. Internet Plug-Ins). How do I enter this on a command line so that terminal recognizes the directory? I know a little Linux but not enough to know how to enter a directory name that has a space in it.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "Terminal doesn't like spaces"?  Please copy-paste exactly what you typed in and exactly what response you got.  Also please edit the question to show what you tried.  In general if you put the filename between single quotes (`'...'`), as I did in my example above, spaces should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/java.security

Comment: I find jdk1.7.0_71.jdk and  jdk1.8.0_121.jdk in those directories, though I have 8.0.161 installed for sure. Any idea where that is? I need to modify java.security.